# C++で配列を扱うプログラムで Abort trap 6のエラーメッセージを出てしまう

Tags: c++, array

行数、列数が９９以下の配列にstdinから読み込んだファイルを配列に格納するプログラムを書いていています。

無事コンパイルが通り期待どおりの結果が実効されるのですが、Abort trap 6エラーメッセージが出てしまいます。

**main関数のコード**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int ROW_MAX = 3;
    const int COL_MAX = 3;
    int row_count=0;
    int col_count=0;
    string line;

    char arr[ROW_MAX][COL_MAX];

    while(getline(cin,line)){ //stdinから読み込み
        int l = line.length();

        if(l > COL_MAX){
            cout << "Column size is too big. Try less than " << COL_MAX << endl;
            return 1; //lineが列の数より多きい場合はエラー
        }

        for(int i=0; i<l; ++i) arr[row_count][i] = line[i];

        ++row_count;
        col_count = l;

        if(row_count > ROW_MAX){ // row_countがROW_MAXより大きい場合は読み取るのをやめる
            --row_count;
            break;
        }

    }

    cout << "row_count : " << row_count << endl;
    cout << "col_count : " << col_count << endl;

    cout << "Input table looks like " << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<row_count; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<col_count; ++j)
            cout << arr[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "It has " << col_count << " columns and " << row_count << " rows." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**stdin するファイルの中身**

```
000
010
000
000
```

**./a.out < ファイル名 の結果**

```
row_count : 3
col_count : 3
Input table looks like 
000
010
000
It has 3 columns and 3 rows.
Abort trap: 6
```

なぜAbort trap 6が出てしまうのかどなたか教えていただけないでしょうかm(_ _)m

Comment: `const int ROW_MAX = 3` としているのに 4 行あるデータを読み込んでいますね。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございますm(_ _)m 3×3の配列以外はreturn 1するようプログラムを修正したのですが、やはりまだabort trap 6 が出てしまっている状態です。引き続き解決策を模索中です。

Comment: 配列(array)の添字(index)は 0-base ですので、、、その変更では修正になりません。`if(row_count > ROW_MAX){ ... }` を削って、`while( row_count < ROW_MAX && getline(cin,line)) { ...` などとすると良いかと思います。

Comment: ご指摘の通り修正させて頂きましたm(_ _)m おかでさまでAbort trap 6は無くなりました。未熟な質問で申し訳ないのですが”配列(array)の添字(index)は 0-base”だとなぜ↑の変更で修正にならないのでしょうか。row_count　を 3に戻してwhileから抜け出せば良いかなと自分では思って実行したのですが何が問題だったのかまだ理解できてないです。

Comment: 0-baseの件理解できました。本当に初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません、助けて頂いて感謝しています!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サイズ3(=ROW_MAX)の配列(arr)に4つの要素を代入しているので、未定義動作になっているのではないでしょうか?

arrはローカル変数、つまりスタック上に確保した変数なので、4つ目の要素代入の際にスタック破壊が発生しており、main関数から戻る際に未定義動作していると予想します。
(Abortなので、それなりに純正常な動作のようですが)

なお、各要素を格納する際に、文字列の終端文字(\0)も入れるようにした方がいいです。
(質問例だと問題になりませんが)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございますm(_ _)m 仰る通りで配列の代入バグをrow_countをチェックすることによって修正させて頂きました。しかしそれでもなおabort trap 6が出現するということで引き続き解決策を模索中です。